# iOS Dynamic Tabs with Storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a main storyboard which consists of a single `UITabBarController`, and each `UITabBarItem` simply takes you to another storyboard. My issue is that not all the tabs should always show. There is anywhere between 2 and 5 tabs, and the combination of tabs can be completely different based on the user.

How does one go about conditionally hiding tabs?
This seems like it should be pretty straight forward but I have not found a general way of going about this.

Comment: Just do it with code.

Comment: @Lumialxk that was my intention...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing something like the following:

```
let user = User.sharedInstance

if let vcs = self.viewControllers {
    var newVcs = [UIViewController]()

    for vc in vcs {
        if let title = vc.title {
            switch title {
            case "Feature1":
                if user.isFeature1Enabled() {
                    newVcs.append(vc)
                }
            case "Feature2":
                if user.isFeature2Enabled() {
                    newVcs.append(vc)
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
}

self.setViewControllers(newVcs, animated: false)
```

I feel like there should be a better way. I was expecting to do something like `something.hide()` but this works.

Answer (score 0):

1.Instantiate view controller form stroryboard.

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "you storyboard name", bundle: nil)  
let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboard id set")
```

2.Create tabbar controller and add child view controller.

```
let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc) // if you didn't ember in navigation controller
tabBarController.addChildViewController(nav)
```

3.Customize tabbar item.

```
nav.tabBarItem.image = ... // your normal image
nav.tabBarItem.selectedImage = ... // your select image
    nav.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue], for: .normal)
nav.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue], for: .selected)
```

Comment: Is there a way to just iterate over the UIViewControllers and conditionally hide them? That is what I was hoping of doing instead of adding in each one from scratch.

Comment: @Lorenzo you can use `tabBarController.setViewControllers(<#T##viewControllers: [UIViewController]?##[UIViewController]?#>, animated: <#T##Bool#>)
`.